# Substitute Array Elements with Hash Values

Tags: perl, date, hash, dictionary

I am trying to code a Perl Script which will take the date in Pattern, October 24, 2011 and convert this to 10,24,2011.

In order to do this I have prepared a Hash which will have the Month Name as a Key and a Numerical value representing Month's position as a Value.

I will read the input string, use a regular expression to extract the month name from above format.

Replace this month name with a value which corresponds to the month as a key.

Here's the script I have coded so far, but it's not working for me.

@dates array will have every element in this format -> October 24, 2011.

```
%days=("January",01,"February",02,"March",03,"April",04,"May",05,"June",06,"July",07,"August",08,"September",09,"October",10,"November",11,"December",12);

@output = map{
$pattern=$_;
$pattern =~ s/(.*)\s/$days{$1};
} @dates;

foreach $output (@output)
{
print $output."\n";
}
```

Here's a little explanation of what I am trying to do with this code.

@output will have the new formatted array with the Month Name replaced by the corresponding Numerical representing it as defined in the Hash.

map function is used to transform the elements of the array on the fly.

a sequence of characters followed by space is the regular expression used to extract the Month Name from pattern, October 24, 2011.

This will be referenced by $1.

I look up the corresponding value for $1 in the hash using, $days{$1}

Comment: Why not use `DateTime`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It looks like a simple syntax error in `$pattern =~ s/(.*)\s/$days{$1};` -- you're missing a third `/` character -- but it'd be easier to give feedback if you give a fully working little script. (Incidentally, CanSpice's suggestion to use `DateTime` is a good one, though I personally found that _some_ date modules are easily available on some Linux distributions and _other_ date modules are easily available on others, so a little research first might be worth the effort.)

Comment: consider writing the `map` statement as `s/../../ for my @output = @dates;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a few problems here. The first is that there is no `use strict;`.

A number with a leading zero is assumed to be in octal format (i.e. base 8) so `08` is invalid. You want one of these:

```
%days = ("January",     1,  "February",     2,  ...
%days = ("January",   "01", "February",   "02", ...
%days = ("January" =>   1,  "February" =>   2,  ...
%days = ("January" => "01", "February" => "02", ...
```

You should also be declaring your variables with `my`:

```
my %days = ...
my @output = ...
```

You're missing the final slash on your substitution, you probably want a comma in there to match your desired output format, and `.*` will eat up more than you want:

```
$pattern =~ s/(\S*)\s/$days{$1}, /;
```

The block for your `map` needs to return the value you want in `@output` but it currently returns 1 (see [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) to learn why); something like this will serve you better:

```
my @output = map {
    my $pattern=$_; # You don't need this, operating on $_ is fine here
    $pattern =~ s/(\S*)\s/$days{$1}, /;
    $pattern
} @dates;
```

If you really want the spaces removed from the output, then this should do the trick:

```
my @output = map {
    my $pattern=$_; # You don't need this, operating on $_ is fine here
    $pattern =~ s/(\S*)\s/$days{$1}, /;
    $pattern =~ s/\s//g;
    $pattern
} @dates;
```

There are more compact ways to do this `map` but I don't want to change too much and confuse you.

And, as mentioned in the comments, you might want to save yourself some trouble and have a look at [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/) and related packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Yeah, I always program using use strict and variables declared using my. Here, I only wanted to the paste the snippet to check the logic. You have given a very nice and clear solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the fact that you pasted non-compiling code (forgot training "/" as sarnold said), your regex is wrong.

You used a GREEDY regex: `.*` - meaning take as many characters as possible while matching. So your regex matched `October 24,` instead if `October`.

You need to do `\S+\s`

Comment: Thanks, yes that REGEX is greedy but I wasn't sure of the workaround.

Comment: There are two - either don't use such a wide match (in other words, my answer - change "." to "\S") - or, as alternative, use non-greedy regex. "perldoc perlre" is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to "substitute array elements with hash values," or do you want to map month names to numbers.  If it's the latter, the following will convert `month_name day year` to `month_number day year` with less code:

```
perl -le '$d=$ARGV[0]; for (qw{Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec}) { $i++; last if $d =~ s/\b$_[^\s]*/$i/i; }; print $d' "october 24, 2011"
```

Comment: In less than 20 mins, I got more than 4 work arounds with detailed solutions. Thanks, you guys are fast! :) I'll learn more about these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some feedback on your code:

- Your pasted code does not compile very well.
- You didn't use strict and warnings.
- 01 to 09 needs to be in double quotes.
- You do not need to reassign `$_` inside your `map` statement.
- `map` needs to end with the value you intend to insert, e.g.: `map { s/(\w+)/$days{$1}/; $_ }`
- `say for @output` looks nicer. =)

Comment: Yes, this was just a snippet do I didn't post the complete thing with use strict, use warnings and declaring variables using my. However, when I program, I do keep these points in mind :) Also, I figured out that octal number error and fixed it. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @TLP - `say` can't be used with old Perl versions. OP didn't indicate his. Reassigning `$_` inside `map` is of course not required, but is generally a Good Practice if the value will be used more than once, for readability's sake. The rest are great points.

Comment: @DVK I don't think it is a good idea to restrict one's answers to be backwards compatible with all versions of perl. I don't think it **is** more readable to reassign `$_`. I think it just makes noise, and `$pattern` is not a very apt name for that variable in any case. If you want readability, don't use `map`, is my suggestion. `s/(\w+)/$days{$1}/ for @array` perhaps.